# Validate a users input from a Google form with a list from Google sheets but reject the submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I've created a musical instrument library system where students can sign instruments in and out of the library using Google forms that then stores the information in a Google sheet. Each instrument has bar codes and students scan the barcode so this input is consistent. The Google sheet has a sheet labeled Status that lists the instruments that are signed out. The list gets updated based on whether the instrument has been signed in or signed out. If the instrument is in the cell is blank if it's out the instrument name appears in that cell. In the sign out Google form I want to create a script that will reject the users submission if the instrument name appears in the Status sheet with the error message "This instrument has already been signed out. Please sign it in first". I'm hoping this is possible. Much of what I've created so far has been based on advice from this site so thank you to all the gurus on here!

In the Google Script Editor for my Google Form named LCS Equipment Check Out I inserted the following code:

```
function validateBarcode(e) {
  var barcode = e.values[1];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KmLTvxD7WpmPHYzvM-NGkCO25BMpSTIQXkmq_lru0s/edit?pli=1#gid=470306544").getSheetByName("Status");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (barcode == data[i][0]) {
      if (data[i][2] % 2 == 1) {
        var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
        form.setCustomClosedFormMessage("This Instrument Is Currently Signed Out. Please Sign It In First Then Return To This Form.");
        form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
        return;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

However it was not successful.

Comment: 1) Google Forms has an `onFormSubmit` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) but event objects are limited and do NOT include an object called `values`. You are thinking of the [Sheets trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). 2) the script is written as if it displays to the respondent in real-time, but the trigger runs **AFTER** the form is submitted. 3) There is no real-time link between forms and sheets, but it _is_ possible to update the form from a sheet; perhaps a workaround exists.

Comment: Thank you Tedinoz. That helps clear a few things up. The code is supposed to check the number of transactions for a given instrument in a called Status and if the number is odd it is meant to reject the submission. If it is even it should accept the submission.

Comment: `That helps clear a few things up`. Excellent, we're making progress. Now we need to understand more about your form; would you please edit your question to describe/explain the type of question that you use for instruments (short answer/ dropdown/checkbox/etc???, the number of instrument questions (perhaps just a single question, or maybe a question for each section/instrument type/etc???), an example of the linked spreadsheet response data as well as the sheet that shows whether the instrument is signed out as well as a description of method used.

Comment: I have two questions in the Google form. The first is the student's name. That's a drop down list that is populated with the kid's names. The second question is the instrument. That's a short answer. The students have barcodes on their instruments and they use a barcode scanner to scan them.

Comment: What if… the purpose of the form is changed from “Sign Out”, to “Request to sign out”. Student submits  barcode, response is received in Spreadsheet, onFormSubmit script checks availability and immediately sends appropriate email to student. Might that work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with Google Apps Script.

Here is a script written by Amit Agarwal, a Google Developer Expert.

```
/**
 * Auto-populate Question options in Google Forms
 * from values in Google Spreadsheet
 *
 * Written by Amit Agarwal (MIT License)
 *
 **/

const populateGoogleForms = () => {
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = 'YourSheetName';
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = 'GoogleFormID';

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const [header, ...data] = ss.getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {
    choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);
  });

  FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID)
    .getItems()
    .map((item) => ({
      item,
      values: choices[item.getTitle()],
    }))
    .filter(({ values }) => values)
    .forEach(({ item, values }) => {
      switch (item.getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        default:
        // ignore item
      }
    });
};
```

Use your own sheet name and Google Form ID in place of `YourSheetName` and `GoogleFormID` in the code.

Without seeing your spreadsheet, I have created a simple sample.  Note that the Spreadsheet needs to be set up with headers that match the Form Questions.  The form entries and update information should be in two separate tabs on the same spreadsheet.

[image: Spreadsheet]

[image: Form]

Using `FILTER` formula, you can populate the "Instrument" column based on each instrument's current availability.  You can run the script manually the first time based on each instrument's current checkout status.  Then have it update with `onFormSubmit` trigger.  When someone returns an instrument the form will get submitted.  The data will get entered into the spreadsheet which will trigger a new Form Update.  This should keep everything up-to-date.

A student will now only be able to select an instrument based on its status.  If a student selects "Return", only those instruments that are currently checked out will appear.  If a student selects "Check Out", only those instruments available will appear.